# match values of arrays with different values and different order php

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have two arrays

```
$array1 = array(
    'categories',
    'questions',
    'difficulties'
);
```

and

```
$array2 = array(
     [0] => 'categories_view',
    [1] => 'categories_delete',
    [2] => 'questions_view',
    [3] => 'questions_edit',
    [4] => 'difficulties_view',
)
```

I want to match values of above arrays for checkbox checked attribute

I tried below code but didn't get proper output.

```
<?php 
foreach ($array1 as $key => $value) { 
?>
 <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-3">
  <b><?php echo ucwords($value); ?></b>
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-2">
  <input type="checkbox" name="role[]" value="<?php echo $value;?>_view" <?php echo $array2[$key] ==  $value."_view". ? $checked : ''; ?> > View
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-2">
  <input type="checkbox" name="role[]" value="<?php echo $value;?>_edit" <?php echo $array2[$key] ==  $value."_edit". ? $checked : '' ; ?> > Edit
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-2">
  <input type="checkbox" name="role[]" value="<?php echo $value;?>_delete" <?php echo $array2[$key] ==  $value."_delete". ? $checked : ''; ?> > Delete
 </div>
<?php
}
?>
```

Output should be 
[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is value have $checked ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simple, just check if required value presents in `$array2` with `in_array` function:

```
<?php
foreach ($array1 as $key => $value) {
?>
 <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-3">
  <b><?php echo ucwords($value); ?></b>
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-2">
  <input type="checkbox" name="role[]" value="<?php echo $value;?>_view" <?php echo in_array($value . "_view", $array2) ? $checked : ''; ?> > View
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-2">
  <input type="checkbox" name="role[]" value="<?php echo $value;?>_edit" <?php echo in_array($value . "_edit", , $array2) ? $checked : '' ; ?> > Edit
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-2">
  <input type="checkbox" name="role[]" value="<?php echo $value;?>_delete" <?php echo in_array($value . "_delete", $array2) ? $checked : ''; ?> > Delete
 </div>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks man I didn't thought that way, value also could be use to check in in_array function. You save my lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php foreach ($array1 as $key => $value) :?>
 <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-3">
  <b><?php echo ucwords($value); ?></b>
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-2">
  <input type="checkbox" name="role[]" value="<?php echo $value;?>_view" <?php echo in_array($value . "_view", $array2) ? $checked : ''; ?> > View
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-2">
  <input type="checkbox" name="role[]" value="<?php echo $value;?>_edit" <?php echo in_array($value . "_edit", , $array2) ? $checked : '' ; ?> > Edit
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-2">
  <input type="checkbox" name="role[]" value="<?php echo $value;?>_delete" <?php echo in_array($value . "_delete", $array2) ? $checked : ''; ?> > Delete
 </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```